# RecyclerView 1.2.0-alpha02: setting shared RecycledViewPool to RV makes MergeAdapter crash and view types in other screens inconsistent

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I use shared **RecycledViewPool** between some Fragments. I decided to try out `MergeAdapter` in one fragment. For that screen, I created a separate adapter for each viewType and overrode `getItemViewType` method to return layout ID as view type.

When I go to any other screen that has shared RecycledViewPool but is not using `MergeAdapter` I see some of the viewHolders from previous screen showing up. When I return back app crashes and in logs I see `ClassCastException` saying that `ViewHolder1` cannot be casted to `ViewHolder2`.

My code looks like this:

```
recyclerView.setRecycledViewPool(sharedViewPool)

val adapter = MergeAdapter(adapter1, adapter2, adapter3, adapter4)
recyclerView.adapter = adapter
```

How to keep shared RecycledViewPool, but eliminate `ClassCastException` and stop showing ViewHolders in other screens where they should not be shown?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After digging more into the documentation I found that the problem was `MergeAdapter` with default configuration.

from [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/MergeAdapter):

> By default, MergeAdapter isolates view types of nested adapters from each other such that it will change the view type before reporting it back to the RecyclerView to avoid any conflicts between the view types of added adapters. This also means each added adapter will have its own isolated pool of RecyclerView.ViewHolders, with no re-use in between added adapters.
>
> If your RecyclerView.Adapters share the same view types, and can support sharing RecyclerView.ViewHolder s between added adapters, provide an instance of MergeAdapter.Config where you set MergeAdapter.Config.isolateViewTypes to false. A common usage pattern for this is to return the R.layout. from the RecyclerView.Adapter.getItemViewType(int) method.

I also read this in [article](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/merge-adapters-sequentially-with-mergeadapter-294d2942127a) written by Florina Muntenescu and for some reason I thought that `isolateViewTypes` is only affecting adapters added to one `MergeAdapter`. **But since in default config it will modify returned view types for each ViewHolder it might (most likely will) cause inconsistency in shared `RecycledViewPool`**. Not sure if it is a bug or expected behaviour. Would be great to hear something from team working on `RecyclerView`.

Solution was setting `isolateViewTypes` to `false`.

```
val adapter = MergeAdapter(
    MergeAdapter.Config.Builder().setIsolateViewTypes(false).build(),
    adapter1, 
    adapter2, 
    adapter3, 
    adapter4
)
```

I think it is pretty easy mistake to make and I hope this solution will save some time for others.